# php function to create array with all categories and subcategories ides

Tags: php, arrays

i wrote a function to create an array with category_id and all subcategories ides, the main category should be selected from the page url example pages.php?category_id = 1,

then the array should be like 1,23,25

"25 is a subcategory for parent 23 and 23 is a subcategory for 1",

i'll use this later to show items with item_cat exist in array example

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_cat IN (1,23,25)
```

the problem is my function is echo in the page, and i'm not sure i wrote it in a correct way here is my function code

```
$category_id=$_REQUEST['category_id'];
function categoriesIdes($parentId, $connection) {
global $category_id;
$sqlCategories = "SELECT * FROM categories 
WHERE category_parent = ".$parentId." ";
$rsCategories = mysql_query($sqlCategories, $connection);
$totalCategoriesRows = mysql_num_rows($rsCategories);

while($rowsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)) {
$catId = $rowsCategories['category_id'];
echo ''.$catId.',' ;
categoriesIdes($catId, $connection);
}
}
$ides = categoriesIdes($category_id, $connection);
$idesall = ''.$category_id.','.$ides.'';
$idesall = substr($idesall,0,-1);
```

Comment: How deep is your category levels?

Comment: no limit the user may add categories and sub categories just need it to loop till the las child (subcategory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly try this:

```
<?php

$category_id=$_REQUEST['category_id'];

function categoriesIdes($parentId, $connection) {

    //not sure why you're using this    
    global $category_id;

    //select all the childeren
    $sqlCategories = "SELECT * FROM categories 
        WHERE category_parent = ".$parentId." ";

    //query
    $rsCategories = mysql_query($sqlCategories, $connection);
    $totalCategoriesRows = mysql_num_rows($rsCategories);


    //will hold categoryIDs found
    $categoryIDs = array();

    //for every child
    while($rowsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)) {

        //child id
        $catID = $rowsCategories['category_id'];

        //add to array
        $categoryIDs[] = $catID;

        //debug
        echo ''.$catID.',' ;

        //find and add the childeren
        $categoryIDs = array_merge($categoryIDs, categoriesIdes($catID, $connection));
    }

    return $categoryIDs;
}

$ides = categoriesIdes($category_id, $connection);

$ids = '';
if (count ($ides) > 0){
    $ids = $category_id .','. implode(',',$ides);
}
else{
    //only 1 id
    $ids = $category_id;

}

echo $ids;

?>
```

Comment: i'm having a small trouble sir, if the array is more than one number example (1, 3) works fine,  but if its only one number the array show like this (1,) 
so how i can get ride of the extra (,) if the array contain one number only ?